# Raster graphics in xterm?

Tags: graphics, terminal, x11, xterm

No, not ASCII graphics, see the screenshot here:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/W3m

[image]

How is that even possible?

I checked the source and it only prints character sequences. However, I am unable to find any reference to graphic drawing or image embedding escape sequences in xterm documentation or elsewhere.

w3m also seems to be the only software doing this.

There *are* vector graphics in Tektronix emulation, but this is done in VT mode.

Maybe I am looking for the wrong thing?

Any idea?

Comment: Here's one method, I don't know if it's what w3m uses: http://pippin.gimp.org/tv/

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It's a cheat.

Note that this feature works only in "supported terminals" -- and by that it meant xterm, and rendering directly on the xterm window via [xv](http://www.trilon.com/xv/).

Or not! Just checked the sources, the file that interests us is [here](http://w3m.cvs.sourceforge.net/viewvc/w3m/w3m/w3mimg/x11/x11_w3mimg.c?view=markup). It's still a hack -- via X11 and GTK!

Comment: That page is awful, it is 1995 again! :) While w3m has an option to display through xv I don't think the two are related. I don't even have an xv package.

Comment: @jbcreix : yeah, had the same '95 feeling ;> -- From the w3m page - Q : How do I change the default image viewer?

A : By default w3m uses xv to view images. If you want to change it into, let's say, 'display', add the following line to ~/.mailcap or /etc/mailcap.

Check your viewer!

Comment: @jbcreix : "use the source Luke" -- found it ;>

Comment: Oh, it was writing its own "w3m image protocol". That's what you get reading a file with no comments. Interesting, but in the end it's just a hack. :(

Comment: This is the only answer which addresses the question.

Answer (score 10):

There is [MLTerm](https://bitbucket.org/arakiken/mlterm), which supports Sixel format (not ReGis commands). It's available for both Linux and Windows.

Otherwise, according to [`man xterm` on Ubuntu 12.04](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man1/xterm.1.html), `xterm` supports Tektronix graphics, which (the man page does tell) use ReGIS commands or Sixel bitmap format, depending on compilation options (I believe [it's Sixel for the XTerm in the Ubuntu package repository](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xterm/297-1ubuntu1)).

One thing to know, is that ReGIS is an instruction set, while Sixel is a bitmap format.

As a side note, there exists a Python package to use Sixel aware terminal emulators: [PySixel](https://github.com/saitoha/PySixel).

I'm interested in the topic too, and may update this answer in the future, with other relevant terminal emulators entries.

Comment: As to xterm, [apparently](http://rullf2.xs4all.nl/sg/doc.html) one should run it with `xterm -ti 340` to enable Sixel rendering. One can then test it e.g. on [a sample "map8.six" image from libsixel repository](https://github.com/saitoha/libsixel/blob/7f7358573f7e4957dd483689782bfc3c127ceba6/images/map8.six). Worked For Me™! (There are other sample images reportedly at ftp://invisible-island.net/temp/SIXEL.tgz)

Comment: The Tektronix emulation is unrelated to the ReGIS and Sixel support; the manual page doesn't imply that it is related.

Answer (score 4):

Higher-end models of Dec VT terminals support [ReGis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ReGIS) and [Sixel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sixel) graphics commands.  If the xterm emulation is good enough, maybe that's how it was done?

Comment: xterm doesn't seem to support these modes. At least all references I found were to them not working.

Comment: It's not a matter of "good enough", but what is targeted: at the point in time when this answer was suggested, the xterm manual was clear that it emulated **vt220** (and ReGIS is not a feature of vt220).  On the other hand, this answer does not address the question.

Answer (score 2):

Xterm supports the sixel and ReGIS protocols which allow rendering graphics directly in the terminal using escape sequences.  However, Unicode interferes with 8 bit escape sequences, so you may need to convert them to 7bit sequences.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sixel

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ReGIS